# How to locate HTML files associated with the mobile view of a theme?

Tags: magento2, store-view, html, custom-theme, mobile-menu

I installed a Magento theme on my server and wanted to make some changes to the menu within the theme.I am able to view the HTML codes related to the desktop view menu in the block section of the Magento Admin Panel like this,

[image]

[image]

I successfully made the desired changes to the HTML code and the menu now appears as desired in the desktop view,
[image]

However, the menu appearance in the **mobile view** differs from my desired outcome and I wish to make changes in this view as well.
[image]

By using the inspect view, I can access the HTML code related to the mobile view menu. However, I can't find a corresponding block for the mobile view menu in the block section of the Magento Admin Panel. So, I want your help in locating the HTML file related to the mobile view menu, in order to make changes. Please anyone can help me in finding the file as I am new to both web development and Magento?

Comment: If answer help, please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the template debuger tools include in magento.

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/debug/

after you can add "?templatehints=magento" in the url and all templates/blocks path are display on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, I faced such a problem, I advise you not to try to do it yourself, but to turn to these guys https://barwenock.com/ I have been working for many years